# Openlayers 3 - how to override handleUpEvent in PinchZoom interaction?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In Openlayers 3 I've been unable to get my attempts at overriding the `ol.interation.PinchZoom`'s `handleUpEvent` to work.  I've tried a few different ways, but but below is a basic example of what I've tried.

This is an attempt to replace the standard `PinchZoom`'s `handleUpEvent` with a custom one, and set this as the only interaction for the map.  However, the event function is never called (never logs anything).

```
function handleUpEvent(evt) {
    console.log("Up event handler");
    return true; //  Stop drag
}

map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [],
    target: 'map',
    controls: controls,
    interactions: [new ol.interaction.PinchZoom({handleEvent: handleUpEvent})],
    view: new ol.View({projection: projCode})
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having posted a similar question on Stack Overflow, I eventually received an answer there.  It seems that `PinchZoom` does not provide an option for overriding the `handleUpEvent`.  I had incorrectly assumed that it inherited this option from its `Pointer` parent class.

It was recommended to me that I would need to use a custom build of Openlayers with modified source code.  Hopefully this may be included in a future version of Openlayers itself.  An example of the modified Openlayers is available there for anybody that's interested:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882212/openlayers3-fractional-zoom-on-touch-device-using-pinch-gesture

In my case, I was wanting to use fractional zoom and avoid the final zoom-to-nearest-native-resolution that happens at the end of a `PinchZoom`.  The example custom build does not provide the option to override `handleUpEvent` as such, but rather provides an option to use fractional zoom, and if this option is enabled, the modified built-in `handleUpEvent` will skip the final animated zoom-to-nearest-native-resolution.

**UPDATE**:  OpenLayers 3.20 includes the PinchZoom behaviour I want by default now.  The old behaviour is now only available by specifying the `constrainResolution` option.